# Find object in multiple arrays by value of specific key

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to find an object in multiple arrays by a `target` value and return the `source` value.

The data looks like this:

```
{
  "something": [
    {
      "type": "static",
      "source": "data-access-select",
      "target": "data-access-graphql"
    },
    {
      "type": "static",
      "source": "return-me",
      "target": "find-me"
    }
  ],
  "anything": [
    {
      "type": "static",
      "source": "data-access-page-index",
      "target": "data-access-graphql"
    }
  ]
}
```

So there are multiple arrays.

```
const depsBuffer = await readFile(
  resolve('node_modules/.cache/nx/nxdeps.json')
)
const deps = JSON.parse(depsBuffer.toString('utf-8')).dependencies

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(deps)) {
  const res = value.find(x => x.target === 'find-me').source
  console.log(res); // expected: 'return-me'
}
```

But with this I do get the ts error `Property 'find' does not exist on type 'unknown'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that TypeScript does not know that `value` is an Array. It sees `value` as `unknown`.

Try specifying a type to describe the expected shape of the JSON

```
interface Dependencies {
  [key: string]: Array<{
    type: string,
    source: string, 
    target: string
  }>;
}

const depsBuffer = await readFile(
  resolve('node_modules/.cache/nx/nxdeps.json')
);
const deps = JSON.parse(depsBuffer.toString('utf-8')).dependencies as Dependencies;

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(deps)) {
  const res = value.find(x => x.target === 'find-me').source;
  console.log(res); // expected: 'return-me'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const deps = {
  "something": [
    {
      "type": "static",
      "source": "data-access-select",
      "target": "data-access-graphql"
    },
    {
      "type": "static",
      "source": "return-me",
      "target": "find-me"
    }
  ],
  "anything": [
    {
      "type": "static",
      "source": "data-access-page-index",
      "target": "data-access-graphql"
    }
  ]
};

const foundElement = Object.values(deps).flat().find(el => el.target === "find-me");
console.log(foundElement.source);
```

Comment: Still get a ts error `Property 'flat' does not exist on type 'unknown[]'`

Comment: falt is used for nested arrays to flat them down exmp: [[a,b,c],[d,e,f]] > [a,b,c,d,e,f]. I gues you doing something wrong, try to consol log your init object whats is giving to you

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
const source = Object.values(deps).reduce((source, array) => {
  const element = array.find(x => x.target === 'find-me');
  if (element) return element.source;
  else return source;
}, null);
```

or this is more similar to your code:

```
for (const [_, value] of Object.entries(deps)) {
  const res = value.find(x => x.target === 'find-me');
  // res is going to be undefined if in the array there is not an object with that target
  if (res) console.log(res.source);
}
```

Comment: While that does work, please provide a small explanation of what went wrong in the original code and how you fixed it.

Comment: updated the response with something more similar to your code

Comment: Still get a ts error `Property 'find' does not exist on type 'unknown'.`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method. if the target is found, then the first element of the array is your answer.

```js
const array = "Your array here";
let result;
for (var key in array) {
    result = array[key].filter(r => r.target === "find-me");
    if(result.length > 0){
        break;
    }
}

if(result.length > 0){
    console.log(result[0].source);
}
```

Comment: Lioness100 thank you very much for the correction. yes, it is Array.prototype.filter() method